# How can I return my own promise?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm working setting up my internal service API for Aurelia, I want to return a Promise that I wrote myself and worry about using fetch later. I set Aurelia up to use Bluebird. How can I manually create the promise to return from a method without getting actual http involved?

I imagine it's basically

```
doAndReturn(): Promise<MyType> {
... stuff
return ... magic create Promise?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to mimic what happens when a promise is resolved and returned, is that correct?

It sounds like your function just needs to return `Promise.resolve(value)`

```
doAndReturn(): Promise<MyType> {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

keep in mind your return type on the function is expecting a Promise to return a value of type `MyType`

Comment: huh, for some reason I didn't think Promise was the right type because Bluebird and Intellij Idea is pointing me to the es6 type... ok then. Thanks